# Image not retrieve from folder

Tags: codeigniter

I am upload the image into database and folder. But when I am trying to retrieve it it will not working.

My code is as below:

```
<img src="<?php echo APPPATH.'modules/employee/image/'.@$userdata[0]->photo;?>" />
```

Give me a solution.

Comment: can you print the $userdata and show us..??

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().'modules/employee/image/'.@$userdata[0]->photo;?>" />
```

Comment: But I am getting full path from avove code only image not display.

Answer (score 0):

Constant **APPPATH** will not give you full path, you must need to use **base_url()** instead, but for using base_url() you also need to define your base_url in **config.php**